# Samson go mic or blue snowball

Tags: microphones

I wanna record music and I'm on a fairly tight budget. The samson go mic doesn't seem bad, but the blue snowball has a stand. also does anyone know how to record quality music? like should i record singing and piano together or should i record them separately?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Music.SE!  Recommendations for equipment are off topic here because they generally require an opinion.  Your last question seems like it would work well here.

Answer (score 1):

As I have learned recently, posting my opinion on specific brands is frowned upon here. What I CAN tell you is that a $100 usb condenser Mic is going to be money well spent if you have no recording equipment at all and have a very small budget.

Your last question is subjective as well. It really depends on your post production capabilities and the sound you want.

The answer: Try both methods. Create two projects and whichever method is best for you is the best method.

Edit: rereading your post I noticed you want to know how to record "quality sounds" which makes me think it's your first time doing this. You've got a bit of a learning curve ahead, and any answer here isn't going to do you justice until you dive in and experience specific problems. I wish you the best of luck and welcome you to the endless search for tone :) good luck!